# subsetting a file alphabetically

Tags: linux

I'm relatively new to linux and I was trying to subset certain rows out of a file alphabetically.  Basically I have a column with 3 or 4 letter symbols (it's trade data, they're ticker symbols) and I want to only save ones between certain times, and certain ticker symbols.  (I want only trades between 2:10 and 3:05 and only trades that occurred in symbols SA through TZ)  I tried this gawk script and get the times right

|gawk '{if $2>1410000 && $2<1505000) print $0}'

This got all the times out that I wanted to.  Is there a similar gawk script (or sed maybe?) that I can do to get rid of all the tickers up to SA, and those after TZ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried something obvious, like `$1 >= "SA" && $1 <= "TZ"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gawk '($2 > 1410000 && $2<1505000) && (substr($1,1,2) >= "SA" && substr($1,1,2) <= "TZ"))'

Note that in awk, an empty action statement "{...}" prints the record.

[edit - cleaned up]